# SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Connection string is not valid [87]. 1

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

I am unable to connect to my MS SQL Server 2019 on my local machine. I am using PHP Version 7.3.28
error statement says "SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Connection string is not valid [87]. 1".

The code is as below:-

```
<?php
try  
{  
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=\DESKTOP-BCN88UC\SQLEXPRESS,1433; Database=test;", "\DESKTOP-BCN88UC\JK", "");

$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
}  
catch(Exception $e)  
{   
die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );   
}  
?>
```

Please help me in connecting to the server.

Comment: The first issue is likely the server parameter: use either `sqlsrv:server=DESKTOP-BCN88UC\SQLEXPRESS;` with an instance name, or `sqlsrv:server=DESKTOP-BCN88UC,1433;` with a port number, but don't try to mix the two.